# Определить дату через определенное кол-во дней

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте. Нужно на JavaScript (jquery) определить какая дата будет через определенное количество дней, дата должна быть вида **dd-mm-yyyy**

На php это можно сделать так: `date("d-m-Y", strtotime('15 days'));`

Нужно именно на JavaScript (jquery).
Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: `objNewDate.SetDate(objOldDate.GetDate + varDaysToAdd)`

Comment: @Akina а как вывести сегодняшнюю дату в формате **dd-mm-yyyy** ?

Comment: `var datNow = new Date(); strNow = datNow.format("dd-mm-yyy");`

Answer (score 3):

Есть хорошая библиотека [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com).
В ней есть функция [add](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/)

Answer (score 2):

Код в две строчки без подключения дополнительных библиотек.

```
var dateNow = new Date();
dateNow.setDate(dateNow.getDate() + days);
```

При этом даже если дата будет больше реального количества дней в месяце, месяц автоматически инкрементируется.

Comment: интересно, а как сделать чтобы дата на выходе была вида **01-01-2018** (день-месяц-год) ? было бы здорово

Answer (score 1):

```js
function get(data, day) {
  data = data.split('-');
  data = new Date(data[2], +data[1] - 1, +data[0] + day, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  data = [data.getDate(), data.getMonth() + 1, data.getFullYear()];
  data = data.join('-').replace(/(^|\/)(\d)(?=\/)/g, "$10$2");
  return data
}
console.log(get("24-12-2018", 2));
```